# custom product variant upload

Tags: mysql, architecture

I'm building a custom eCommerce solution for a client. I came up with this database design:

```
+---------------+     +---------------+
| PRODUCTS      |-----<     SKUS      |
+---------------+     +---------------+
|      id       |     |      id       |
|     name      |     |  product_id   |
+---------------+     |      sku      |
        |             |     price     |
        |             |      qty      |
        |             +---------------+
        |                     |
+-------^-------+      +------^------+
| VARIANTS      |------< SKU_VALUES  |
+---------------+      +-------------+
|       id      |      |      id     |
|  product_id   |      | product_id  |
|     name      |      | variant_id  |
+---------------+      |variant_option_id   |
        |              |    sku_id   |
        |              +------v------+
+-------^-------+             |
|VARIANT_OPTIONS|-------------+
+---------------+
|      id       |
|  product_id   |
|  variant_id   |
|     name      |
+---------------+
```

variants and its options are dynamically added by the admin. So for example lets say we have a T-shirt it can have many colors and sizes. Example

```
T-shirt :color=red,blue :size=small,large
```

This is would be represented in the database like so:

```
products:
 ------------------
|  id  |    name   |
 ------------------
|  1   |  t-shirt  | 
 ------------------

variants:
 ------------------------------
|  id  |  product_id  |  name  |
 ------------------------------
|  1   |      1       |  size  |
 ------------------------------
|  2   |      1       |  color |
 ----------------------------

variant_options:
 ---------------------------------------------
|  id  |  product_id  |  variant_id  |  name  |
---------------------------------------------
|  1   |      1       |      1       |  small |
---------------------------------------------
|  2   |      1       |      1       |  large |
----------------------------------------------
|  3   |      1       |      2       |  red |
---------------------------------------------
|  4   |      1       |      2       |  blue |
----------------------------------------------

skus:
 -----------------------------------------------
|  id  |  product_id  |  sku  |  price  |  qty  |
------------------------------------------------
|  1   |      1       | 4xx01 |  140    |   5   |
------------------------------------------------
|  2   |      1       | 4xx02 |  140    |   10  |
------------------------------------------------
|  3   |      1       | 4xx03 |  160    |   8   |
------------------------------------------------
|  4   |      1       | 4xx04 |  160    |   15  |

sku_values:
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  product_id  |  variant_id  |  variant_option_id  |  skud_id  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |      1       |       1      |         1           |      1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |      1       |       2      |         3           |      1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3   |      1       |       1      |         1           |      2    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  4   |      1       |       2      |         4           |      2    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  5   |      1       |       1      |         2           |      3    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  6   |      1       |       2      |         3           |      3    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  7   |      1       |       1      |         2           |      4    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  8   |      1       |       2      |         4           |      3    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What do you guys think of this implementation? is there a better way? The main thing that I see as an issue is when I need to select the specific product so for example if a user selects the `large red t-shirt` this would be my retrieval process:

```
I would go to the sku_values table

select sku_id from sku_values where product__id = 1 and variant_id = 1 and variant_option_id = 2; returns  3,4
select sku_id from sku_values where product_id = 1 and variant_id = 2 and variant_option_id = 3; returns  1,3

now i know the sku_id I need is 3
```

That to me doesn't feel very efficient; however I can't think of anything better and I've been at this for a few days.

Comment: Don't care for it. You're storing price and quantity along with the item. You are likely going to be changing the quantity with some frequency. That means you'll need to update that table which may conflict with a basic read to get the sku. When did *anything* happen? My price today is 1.30 and I observe I sold X units in a week. I increase my price to 1.50 and now I'm moving Y units in a week. Your current design does not support the ability to track changes in price and correlate that to anything.

Comment: Why would your query not be `SELECT S1.sku_id FROM sku_values S1 INNER JOIN sku_values S2 ON S1.product_id = S2.product_id AND S1.variant_id <> S2.variant_id AND S1.variant_option_id <> S2.variant_option_id WHERE S1.product_id = 1 and S1.variant_id = 1 AND S1.variant_option_id = 2 AND S2.variant_option_id = 3`  At this point, I got tired of trying to think out your filter but join the sku_value tables together where the product is the same but the variants and sub variants differ.

Comment: I think you'll run into a special ring of hell when users flub an association and you get Size of Red and Color of XXL but that's just speculation

Comment: @billinkc what approach do suggest or how can i avoid that?

Comment: @billinkc I was thinking of having a product_variant table where the type is included so a pivot table for product and variants with a third field variant_option

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with the others, it wouldn't be the best to have a separate table with your SKU's/Quantities. You'd wanna add a field or something in the product table with the unique sku, and with each product variation the SKU would have a modifier added on to it, or something along those lines.

I wouldn't be the one to go in depth and explain a better structure, simply because of the fact that I wouldn't know the best practices since I am not quiet an "expert" in dealing with product variants and such, but one thing I do know quite well is how Magento lays out their product variant tables. If you wanted to base your structure off of Magento's that would probably be a smart idea since theirs is tried and proven and it would provide you an easy backbone, and allow you to explore and customize it to your needs. Check this out:
[image]
The way their database is setup is they have a product entity table where all the actual products reside, in there they have a couple columns like the name or SKU.

Then from there they gave a couple of attribute tables. These are separated by datatypes, varchar, int, decimal, etc... in these tables is where all the attributes for a product reside, like sizes, colors, images, etc. They actually have a list of all the attributes in an eav_attribute table. They also have separate attribute type tables that show available attributes for products or categories also.

Their database structure is far too complex to go on about in this answer, but if you want to learn more I suggest installing it and taking a look at it, maybe create a couple products to see how the relationships work too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it makes a whole lot of sense to have a product and SKUs table. Either that or you might consider modifying them. I've worked with enterprise point-of-sale systems and that design is not used. Essentially, your product table is your SKUs table because honestly, how many of the same products are going to have multiple SKUs? The whole point of a SKU or PLU is to match one-to-one. Now, you might create a department association, in which many items belong to a single department.

For your `variant_options`, it seems superfluous to have an `id` column. Your primary key in that case would be the combination of `product_id` and `variant_id`.

I agree with @billinkc that you can royally screw up the associations quite easily. I think you would be better of creating separate tables for each variant. You might create a table `sizes` with all possible sizes XS, S, M, L, ... and an intermediate table `sizes_linked` to associate the possible sizes with each product. Do the same thing for color choices.

I also wouldn't keep the quantity in the product or SKU table. That should be in an inventory table or similar which would keep track of all product quantity sales (-) and receiving (+) for each item. Just sum the quantity for each item to get your final quantity on-hand. The regular retail price can stay in the product/sku table, but you would want another table to keep tack of promotion/sale prices. If you wish to record price change history, you would want another table listing the sku, timestamp, and price change to/from.